# FocusOut event not being triggered on input box inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an input box inside an iframe. I have attached `keypress`, `input` and `focusout` event listeners on the input box like this :

```
$("iframe").contents().find('#testDiv').on('keypress input focusout', 'input', function(event) {
  alert(event.type);
});
```

Both `keypress` and `input` events are getting fired on the input box inside the iframe. However the `focusout` event is not getting fired on blur of the input box.

If the input box is not placed inside an iframe, the same syntax and event binding works fine. All the three events get fired on the input box that's not inside the iframe.

**NOTE :** I'm using event delegation because the content in the iframe is dynamic.

**HTML Markup :**

```
<iframe>
  <body>
  </body>
</iframe>
<div id="testDiv1">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**Javascript Code :**

```
var $iframe = $("iframe");
var iframe = $iframe[0];
var doc = iframe.document;
var content = '<div id="testDiv"><input type="text" /></div>';
if (iframe.contentDocument) {
  doc = iframe.contentDocument;
} else if (iframe.contentWindow) {
  doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
}
doc.open();
doc.writeln(content);
doc.close();

$("iframe").contents().find('#testDiv').on('keypress input focusout', 'input', function(event) {
  alert(event.type);
});

$('#testDiv1').on('keypress input focusout', 'input', function(event) {
  alert(event.type);
});
```

Here is a mockup of what I have tried : [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/74upc80y/)

Please help!! I cannot move out the input box from the iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly, focusin and focusout are two events made by IE that supports bubbling up. However jquery simulate this events for the rest of the browsers.

Secondly, only trusted targets can be used for event delegation (see link: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-focusout)

Even targeting the events to the input (see below), only blur and focus gets triggered (tested in Chrome).

```
$("iframe").contents().find('#testDiv input').on('focusout focusin focus blur', function(event) {
  alert('lol: ' + event.type);
});
```

So I guess, there's no straight answer for that. You may need to add some JS on the iframe content that can comunicate this event to the parent frame.

Comment: Exactly what I was just testing. I can confirm that focus and blur are the only events triggered from within the iframe

Comment: Dang! Does that mean there's no way I can delegate a `blur` or `focus` event inside an iframe??

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information :). I should accept this answer but will wait for some more responses.